# Como apagar um arquivo especifico PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo Python e estou tentando fazer um código onde eu listo duas pastas, comparo os itens em comum. Obtendo o resultado eu tenho que apagar o item da pasta antiga e mover o item da pasta nova para a antiga, porém não estou conseguindo excluir o arquivo listado pelo resultado da interseção das pastas :/

```
#listagem de diretorios
pastaOld = 'C:/Users/administrador/Desktop/Backups/BackOld/'
pastaNew = 'C:/Users/administrador/Desktop/Backups/BackNew/'
serv = 'C:/Users/administrador/Desktop/Server/'

old = os.listdir(pastaOld)
new = os.listdir(pastaNew)
server = os.listdir(serv)


#interseção dos nomes
firstOld = [old.strip().split(' ')[0] for old in old]
firstNew = [new.strip().split(' ')[0] for new in new]
firstServer = [server.strip().split(' ')[0] for server in server]


interNew = list(set(firstOld).intersection(firstNew))
interServer = list(set(firstNew).intersection(firstServer))
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que a forma de remover arquivos em python é assim:

```
import os
os.remove("caminho/nome_do_arquivo.extensao")
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que vi seu código tem algumas partes desnecessárias, eu removi e atualizei. Como você disse que esta tentando mover os arquivos entre duas pastas eu exclui isso do código:

```
serv = 'C:/Users/administrador/Desktop/Server/'
```

```
server = os.listdir(serv)
```

Não precisamos disso também:

```
#interseção dos nomes
firstOld = [old.strip().split(' ')[0] for old in old]
firstNew = [new.strip().split(' ')[0] for new in new]
firstServer = [server.strip().split(' ')[0] for server in server]
```

Código atualizado:

```
import os
import shutil

pastaOld = 'C:/Users/administrador/Desktop/Backups/BackOld/'
pastaNew = 'C:/Users/administrador/Desktop/Backups/BackNew/'

#pegando a lista de arquivos dentro de cada pasta
old = os.listdir(pastaOld)
new = os.listdir(pastaNew)

print('old: {}'.format(old))
print('new: {}'.format(new))

#fazendo a interseção de cada pasta e imprimindo
inter = list(set(old).intersection(new))
print('intersection: {}'.format(inter))

# removendo os items da pasta antiga
[os.remove(pastaOld + item) for item in inter]

# movendo os arquivos da pasta new para a pasta old
[shutil.move(pastaNew + item, pastaOld + item) for item in new]
```

Espero que te ajude!